# Issue with assembly createinstance and crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I load an assembly

```
private System.Reflection.Assembly;
object myData;

myAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("C:\\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll");
```

then i create an instance.

```
myData=myAssembly.CreateInstance("CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument", true);
```

this myData always returns null, any thought why it is returning null where as myAssembly has the assembly information and its public key token?

Comment: I will be happy to post an example of something that you could try.. question do you want the .dll to load from the same location where you are running the application..??

Comment: Dll will be loaded from the file path into the assmebly using load file, then i am using CreateInstance using specified type, then i am using GetMethod of reflection, however the CreateInstance always returns null.

Comment: Change my example below to fit your DLL that you are trying to load.. notice how I am getting the Type.. also look into Activator.CreateInstance.. I will post how to do that below in one second

Answer (score 0):

try something like the following below..

```
// dynamically load assembly from file Test.dll
Assembly myData = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll");

// get type of class Calculator from just loaded assembly
Type myData = myData.GetType("CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports")

// create instance of class Calculator
object myDataInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myData);
```

[Reflection Examples C#](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/)

Comment: How do i get for ReportDocument?

Comment: is ReportDocument a Property of what you are trying to get..? if so change the CrystalDecisions to ReportDocument.CrystalReports

Comment: Type myData returns me null, where as Assembly myData on the first for loadfile returns me assembly information.

System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly]: {CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
GlobalAssemblyCache: false
EntryPoint: null

Any thought?

Comment: can you try the example first before we move on to your next question, unless what I've suggested has already worked for you..thanks

Comment: Ok so it's loading now where it didn't in the beginning..?

Comment: No it didn't load i tried your code, the first line works, the second line returns null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15369/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-sharpeye500)

Comment: [Don't make edits like this again](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11961361/2).  It's considered an abuse of the edit system.  If you do, further moderator action may be taken.